# The operation has timed out while reading xml file

Tags: xml, httpwebrequest, timeout, system.net, system.net.webexception

I am getting the following error while I am reading an remote xml file to convert currency on HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() section.

the method that I used TugberkUgurlu_CurConverter.ConverterClass.ConvertActionForTL() is reading an xml file and get a currency value.

but suddenly, I started getting these errors. how can I prevent them? thanks !

> System.Net.WebException: The operation
>   has timed out Generated: Mon, 28 Mar
>   2011 19:33:48 GMT
>
> System.Net.WebException: The operation
>   has timed out    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri
>   uri, ICredentials credentials)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri
>   uri, ICredentials credentials)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri
>   absoluteUri, String role, Type
>   ofObjectToReturn)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object
>   xmlResolver)    at
>   System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object
>   userData)    at
>   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack
>   compressedStack, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>   at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument
>   doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader)    at
>   TugberkUgurlu_CurConverter.ConverterClass.ConvertActionForTL(CurrencyForTLConvert
>   SelectCurrency, Decimal
>   YourPriceToConvert)

Comment: Please show the XML you're trying to load. I believe the stack trace is telling you that the XML includes a reference to an entity which it is attempting to resolve to an external URL - a URL which is not responding.

Comment: @John thanks for the reply. here is the url. http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml I am in Turkey now and I can view the file. but the exception was thrown by the request in the UK two times today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with the file you linked, and neither does XMLSpy.

You say it's a problem occasionally, and the file contains currency conversion values, which are likely to change frequently. Perhaps the file is occasionally bad?

Perhaps you should try loading the file as a text file first, and save it to disk. Then load the XmlDocument from the file on disk. That way, if it fails, you've still got the bad file to look at.

Comment: that's a very good idea. but is there any sample that shows how to load the file as a text file first, and save it to disk. Or can you give a heads-up here?

Comment: I have managed to log the error and the user which faced the error. I have told the customer that the problem was momentary and to try again. the stack trace I have given is the second time error. So I can't tell to try again :)

Comment: Use [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194.aspx)

Comment: thanks. I will give it a try. is there any chance that I can save it to the cache and use it from there. I do not wanna save it to the disk

Comment: You can, but I'm thinking of this as a debugging mechanism. Hopefully, once you find out what the problem is, you'll fix it and won't need this.